# Main window Handle by process name

Tags: delphi

Delphi Xe, Win7x64

How do I get the Main Window Handle, or at least a class, or a window name (if that process has only one window) from  the process name (a full path to exe-file).

Example:

```
 function MyGetWinHandle(path:String):HWND;
 ...
 handle := MyGetWinHandle('c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe');
```

Comment: You should try to re-word the question, as is, it's kind of hard to understand.

Comment: I think it's possible to figure out. So I edited it.  It's basically a dual question. (1) Get process ID from name or path of process, (2) get window handles from active processes.

Comment: C++ dual question not interesting me

Comment: @Gu.: What? When Warren P said that this is a 'dual question', he simply meant that your question consists of two parts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with Petesh that you would need to enumerate the top level windows and check the module file name of the process that created it. To help you get started on enumerating top level windows here is a delphi implementation of doing it.

First you need some way of communicating with the EnumWindows method when it calls back to you. Declare a record for that, which will hold the file name of the module you want to find and a handle to the process when it is found:

```
TFindWindowRec = record
  ModuleToFind: string;
  FoundHWnd: HWND;
end;
```

Then you need to declare and implement the call back function that the EnumWindows method is going to call for each top level window:

```
function EnumWindowsCallBack(Handle: hWnd; var FindWindowRec: TFindWindowRec): BOOL; stdcall;
```

Please note the `stdcall;` at the end of the declaration. This specifies the calling convention which is important because Delphi's default calling convention is different from the Windows API's calling convention.

The implementation of your call back function could look like:

```
function EnumWindowsCallBack(Handle: hWnd; var FindWindowRec: TFindWindowRec): BOOL; stdcall;
const
  C_FileNameLength = 256;
var
  WinFileName: string;
  PID, hProcess: DWORD;
  Len: Byte;
begin
  Result := True;
  SetLength(WinFileName, C_FileNameLength);
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(Handle, PID);
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, PID);
  Len := GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, 0, PChar(WinFileName), C_FileNameLength);
  if Len > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(WinFileName, Len);
    if SameText(WinFileName, FindWindowRec.ModuleToFind) then
    begin
      Result := False;
      FindWindowRec.FoundHWnd := Handle;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Handle is the handle of the top level window currently being processed by EnumWindows. You use it to get the module's file name of that window. The result of the call back determines whether EnumWindows should continue enumerating windows or not. Return false when you have found what you are looking for.

Of course you still need to set the whole enumeration operation in motion:

```
var
  FindWindowRec: TFindWindowRec;

function IsNotePadOpen: Boolean;
begin
  FindWindowRec.ModuleToFind := 'c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe';
  FindWindowRec.FoundHWnd := 0;
  EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsCallback, integer(@FindWindowRec));
  Result := FindWindowRec.FoundHWnd <> 0;
end;
```

Please note that the above code will find the first notepad window enumerated by the EnumWindows method, there may be more, there may be none. It's up to you to decide how to handle those situations.

The Main window can be invisible so you could add `and (IsWindowInvisble(Handle))` after `If (Len > 0)` in the call back function.

Comment: I simply could not pseudo-code enough to make it work as I was on a mac at the time. Nice, helpful answer.

Comment: @Petesh, no worries, we've all been in that situation and the links you provided should also have got OP started. Thanks for the thumbs up.

Comment: You should maybe mention, that in order to use ``GetModuleFileNameEx`` function the ``PsAPI`` unit must be used. I tried with the ``GetModuleFileName`` from ``Windows`` and it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to walk all the top-level windows, and then use [GetWindowModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633517%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to find out what application created it.