# Collect all active window class names

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, window, delphi-7

Many programs (True Transparancy and others) can get all active or running in background window class names like this one:

Delphi 7 Object Inspector name is `tpropertyinspector`

Opera main window class name is `operawindowclass`
etc.

So how to get any opened window class name in Delphi?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call `EnumWindows` to get all the top level windows. Then call `GetClassName` to find out the window class name for each window. If you also wish to probe child windows then call `EnumChildWindows` on each top level window.

Call GetClassName like this:

```
var
  ClassName: string;
  len: Integer;
...
SetLength(ClassName, 256);
len := GetClassName(window, PChar(ClassName), Length(ClassName));
if len=0 then
  RaiseLastOSError;
SetLength(ClassName, len);
```

Comment: @Robrok I believe there's even an example for EnumWindows somewhere in the VCL source code.

Comment: @RobRok: Pardon me for tooting my own horn, but have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806911/main-window-handle-by-process-name/6808215#6808215 Searching for "[Delphi] EnumWindows" on SO would have turned it up in the third question of the list...

Comment: @robrok marjan is exactly right - now you know the name of the functions, searching will get you home

Comment: I don't understand what these comments meen. I just want to have a tlistview on my form and when i click button or something, the list fills with all window names, like in true transparency (exclude manager box)

Comment: The comments mean that you can find sample code on the web by using websearch. Marjan has given you a link to do so.

Comment: There is something like i want but i dont understand it: http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/l/aa080304a.htm

Comment: This can get application title but i need window class name: http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=137431

Comment: @Robrok, instead of using GetWindowText to get the windows title, use GetClassName to, well, get the class name. <g> If you don't understand the code, then ask about the things you don't understand.

Comment: [The maximum length for lpszClassName is 256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I've got no problem with 666.. :)

Comment: @sertac I didn't know there was a maximum but since it's not user visible data that seems like a sensible design.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the [`GetClassName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in the Windows API (same way in Delphi as in any language).