# Change form borders from another application

Tags: c++, c, delphi, window, border

I am now trying to solve a problem with a gamelauncher window..
so my question is:

How could I change form propierties (I need to make the form with rounded borders) of a window of another process? Or could even be in the same process because I could do the work injecting/hooking a DLL into.

[Click to see what I mean I want to do](http://prntscr.com/4w5db1)

Comment: It all depends on how the other application is implemented.

Comment: Is there any 'commom' mode? or maybe a few of them? I guess the launcher was created with C++ positioning the components into the window

Comment: Ask the author of the other app for help.

Comment: I cant do this, its an old application. That was a 'hack idea'.

Comment: So start hacking then. Work out how this app is implemented. If you aren't already familiar with Win32 then this is not the way to start.

Comment: It appears you want to remove one pixel from the corner. If that's the magnitude of "problem" you face, I envy you. Anyway, I assume you know how you achieved that corner effect on *your* program, so what's preventing you from applying that same effect elsewhere?

Comment: Is it really a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure TForm6.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  hWndX : HWND;
  hRegX: HRGN;
begin
  hWndX := FindWindow(nil,PChar('YourWindowName'));
  if hWndX <> 0  then
  begin
    hRegX := CreateEllipticRgn(1, 1, 300, 300);
    SetWindowLong(hWndX, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hWndX, GWL_STYLE) and not WS_BORDER and not WS_SIZEBOX and not WS_DLGFRAME );
    SetWindowPos(hWndX, hWndX, Left, Top, Width, Height, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    SetWindowRgn(hWndX, hRegX, True);
  end
  else
  MessageBox(Handle,PChar('Cant find the window andle'),PChar('Error!'),0)
end;
```

All these API calls look the same in all languages.

Comment: **Really?** For starters, your answer is fundamentally the same as mine, only you did the askers homework instead of pointing the right direction. Further on _your answer is incorrect_ in certain points: **1)** It searches for a window name while the question was about a window of a process. **2)** Your code repositions the found window on top of your form. **3)** Your solution heavily _truncates_ the target form. **4)** Your code creates an elliptic form why the question was about rounded edges (well an ellipse **has** round edges, so in a certain evil manner this is not an error).

Comment: Did you see the picture? I knew the steps! Just didnt know I could use another window handle. Stop beeing like that. -.-

Comment: @ThiagoMarquezini - Well, I have provided information about you can use the handle of another window (and a stackoverflow link on how to do that).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is:

**1)** [Get the window handle of the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806911/main-window-handle-by-process-name) you want to "hack".

**2)** Create a region with rounded shape. I usually use the [CreatePolyRgn()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183511(v=vs.85).aspx) API for that purpose.

**3)** Apply the region to the form using the [SetWindowRgn()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145102(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

***)** Please note that some applications control their regions and will override your settings. (But its not very probable.)

Comment: Instead of `CreatePolyRgn()` **API** you might use the `CreateRoundRectRgn()` **API**. The result will not be as nice, but it is much easier to use.